# Template Function results in Identifier not found

Tags: c++, templates, prototype, compiler-errors

I've created this template, and put it at the very top of my .cpp above main() but I am still getting the following

> error: C3861: 'ConvertNumbertoString': identifier not found.

Here is the template:

```
template<class T>
string ConvertNumberstoString(T number)
{
    string outPut;
    stringstream convert;

    convert << number;
    outPut = convert.str();

    return outPut;
}
```

I know this is probably a stupid function to most of you guys, but it's what I need at the moment.

I can't figure out how to get rid of this error so that I can use it in my program.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `ToString()` would be a better name for the function.

Comment: You need to show how you use the function; that's where the error is being generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to return a string from the function template:

```
// In your cpp:

template<class T>
string ConvertNumberstoString(const T &number)
{
    stringstream convert;
    convert << number;
    return convert.str();
}

int main()
{
    string s = ConvertNumberstoString(42);
}
```

Comment: @JeramyRR: We don't need that kind of language here.